# onmouseover & onmouseleave functions not working properly

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm new to this site and relatively new to web development. I was trying to incorporate javascript to this webpage I made with just HTML & CSS. This webpage is basically an online store for certain products and what I was trying to do was that when someone has their mouse over one of the products, it would provide some details such as the name of the product and the price and when they move the mouse out, it would go back to just an image of the product. For some reason, with my code, it will change the elements so that it shows the details but it won't change back to the original image after the mouse moves away.

I've tried everything I could think of and the goal of this project was to make sure I had an understanding of javascript so I was trying to do this without any jquery. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the code:

```
        //Holds all div elements with class attribute "productlink" which hold the product images
        var products = document.getElementsByClassName("productlink");

        //When this function is called, the product image is changed to show an image of the product, the name and price
        //classNum - specifc class element being called
        //priceAmount - price of product
        //describe - Description/Name of the product
        function hoverDetails(classNum, priceAmount, describe) {
            //Div container for details, image of product, price of product and description
            var divContainer = document.createElement("div");
            var image = document.createElement("img");
            var price = document.createElement("p");
            var description = document.createElement("p");

            var priceTextNode = document.createTextNode(priceAmount);
            var descriptionTextNode = document.createTextNode(describe);

            description.appendChild(descriptionTextNode);
            price.appendChild(priceTextNode);
            image.src = picArray[classNum];

            divContainer.setAttribute("class", "newdiv");
            image.setAttribute("class", "newimg");
            price.setAttribute("class", "itemprice")
            description.setAttribute("class", "itemdescription");

            products[classNum].parentNode.style.textDecoration = "none";

            divContainer.appendChild(image);
            divContainer.appendChild(description);
            divContainer.appendChild(price);

            //This should replace the current image with the details specified eariler
            //childNode is set to 1 due to a #text node in the div
            products[classNum].replaceChild(divContainer, products[classNum].childNodes[1]);
        }

        //This function, when called, replaces the detailed product with just an image of the product
        function originalImage(classNum) {
            var image = document.createElement("img");

            image.setAttribute("class", "display_image");
            image.src = picArray[classNum];

            products[classNum].replaceChild(image, products[classNum].childNodes[1]);
        }
```

Here is the element that is referencing these functions:

```
   <a href="#">
   <div class="productlink" onmouseover="hoverDetails(0,'$85.95','Printer') "onmouseout="originalImage(0)">
   <img class="display_image" src="images/printer1.jpg" />
   </div>
```

Don't the mind the variable names and I'm sorry if my code seems too much. Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: Just to let people know, both functions work. The onmouseleave event works when the onmouseover event is not attached. Additionally, the code works when the onmouseover event is replaced with onclick. When I replace onmouseover with onmouseenter, the code works once but never again. This is very strange.

Comment: uhh why did you append elements with variables? Why didn't you just have them sit statically in the HTML file?

Answer (score 0):

There is actually another mouse event called onmouseout. Add another attribute called `onmouseout="removeHoverDetails()"` and then inside of removeHoverDetails() select everything and say .visibility = "hidden"; Or whatever way you want to use to get rid of the elements in the popup. Also check out w3schools tutorial on onmouseover and onmouseout: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onmouseover.asp

Comment: I tried using omouseout before but that gave me the same results. But I'll try changing visibility and see if that works for me. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Yeah, didn't work for me. I added an edit to give more clarification with what I'm dealing with.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I found the solution to my problem. I put the onmouseover event on the image element of the "productlink" div an left the onmouseout event on the div and looks to be working fine.